# How many times does the word mubeen appear in the quran

Tags: quran

How many times has the word "Mubeen" been repeated in the noble Quran?

Answer (score 2):

The word Mubeen appears 84 times in the Quran and 125 times in total(i.e with words like mubeena, Almubeen....)

Here is a [reference](http://www.alawfa.com/Go.aspx?keyword=%D9%85%D8%A8%D9%8A%D9%86) with all the verses that include Mubeen (it is in Arabic but you can take the verse number and view it at

```
http://quran.com/number_of_sura/number_of_verse
```

For example here is a [link](http://quran.com/26/2) to the first match.

For Later reference you can view the number of repetition of any word at this site:

> http://www.alawfa.com/

It needs to be in arabic.